# Inserting integer array with postgresql in C (libpq)

Tags: c, arrays, postgresql, insert, libpq

I'm trying to post an integer array into my postgresql database. I'm aware that I could format everything as a string and then send that string as one SQL command. However, I believe the PQexecParams function should also bring some help. However, I'm kind of lost as how to use it.

```
    //we need to convert the number into network byte order
    int val1 = 131;
    int val2 = 2342;
    int val3[5] = { 0, 7, 15, 31, 63 };
    //set the values to use
    const char *values[3] = { (char *) &val1, (char *) &val2, (char *) val3 };
    //calculate the lengths of each of the values
    int lengths[3] = { sizeof(val1), sizeof(val2), sizeof(val3) * 5 };
    //state which parameters are binary
    int binary[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };

    PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn, "INSERT INTO family VALUES($1::int4, $2::int4, $3::INTEGER[])", 3, //number of parameters
            NULL, //ignore the Oid field
            values, //values to substitute $1 and $2
            lengths, //the lengths, in bytes, of each of the parameter values
            binary, //whether the values are binary or not
            0); //we want the result in text format
```

Yes this is copied from some tutorial.
However this returns :

```
 ERROR:  invalid array flags
```

Using a conventional method does work:

```
PQexec(conn, "INSERT INTO family VALUES (2432, 31, '{0,1,2,3,4,5}')");
```

Inserts data just fine, and I can read it out fine as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`libpq`'s `PQexecParams` can accept values in text or binary form.

For text values, you must `sprintf` the integer into a buffer that you put in your `char**` values array. This is usually how it's done. You can use text format with query parameters, there is no particular reason to fall back to interpolating the parameters into the SQL string yourself.

If you want to use binary mode transfers, you must instead ensure the integer is the correct size for the target field, is in network byte order, and that you have specified the type OID. Use `htonl` (for `uint32_t`) or `htons` (for `uint16_t`) for that. It's fine to cast away signedness since you're just re-ordering the bytes.

So:

- You **cannot** ignore the OID field if you're planning to use binary transfer
- Use `htonl`, don't brew your own byte-order conversion
- Your `values` array construction is wrong. You're putting `char**`s into an array of `char*` and casting away the wrong type. You want `&val1[0]` or (equivalent in most/all real-world C implementations, but not technically the same per the spec) just `val1`, instead of `(char*)&val1`
- You cannot assume that the on-wire format of `integer[]` is the same as C's `int32_t[]`. You **must** pass the type OID `INT4ARRAYOID` (see `include/catalog/pg_type.h` or `select oid from pg_type where typname = '_int4'` - the internal type name of an array is `_` in front of its base type) and **must** construct a PostgreSQL array value compatible with the `typreceive` function in `pg_type` for that type (which is `array_recv`) if you intend to send in binary mode. In particular, *binary-format arrays have a header*. You cannot just leave out the header.

In other words, the code is broken in multiple exciting ways and cannot possibly work as written.

Really, there is *rarely any benefit in sending integers in binary mode*. Sending in text-mode is often actually faster because it's often more compact on the wire (small values). If you're going to use binary mode, you will need to understand how C represents integers, how network vs host byte order works, etc.

Especially when working with arrays, text format is easier.

`libpq` could make this a lot easier than it presently does by offering good array construct / deconstruct functions for both text and binary arrays. Patches are, as always, welcome. Right now, [3rd party libraries like `libpqtypes`](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/) largely fill this role.

Comment: The postgresql documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN) says OIDs can be avoided even for binary data by suffixing the parameter symbol with the type (e.g. `$1::bigint`). Is this wrong?

Comment: @undur_gongor it is correct for text format. Not sure about binary.