# String formatting settings in PostgreSQL/libpq

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I am using libpq for my C/C++ application to interface with PostgreSQL.

My queries are parameterised and in text (not binary) format (using `PQexecParams`), and they return data that might be a `text`, `text[]`, `int4range`, or other complex types.  However, libpq seems to format strings based on rules that don't seem to be well-documented.

For example, for a string array, libpq returns something like that:

```
{abc,def,"h,h","h\"h",h'h,"h h"}
```

when the array, in C style, would look like this:

```
{"abc","def","h,h","h\"h","h'h","h h"}
```

libpq seems to place double quotes and escape characters (`\`) where it deems fit.

For a string (not string array), libpq will instead not place double quotes at all.

As any printable character might possibly be stored in my strings, is there a way to force libpq or PostgreSQL to return strings and string arrays in a consistent format for easy consumption by my C/C++ application?

Comment: This has nothing to do with libpq, that's the standard [output syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) for PostgreSQL's arrays (and in fact, it is more complicated than that if you want to support arbitrary indexed arrays too). `libpqtypes` might does what you need: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802669/inserting-integer-array-with-postgresql-in-c-libpq).

Comment: @pozs That makes sense, thanks!  Eventually I used `array_to_string` to get PostgreSQL to send the data as a plain string.  For the integer and timestamp types, I had already written an interface that looks like this: `pqclient.query("SELECT my_id, my_text FROM my_table WHERE data = $1;", make_tuple(12345), tuple<int64_t, string>(), [](optional<CommandError>&& error, vector<tuple<int64_t, string>>&& results){ ... });`, which solves simple types for now.